# Delete a block of lines from a file

Tags: c#

I have a task to delete some lines from a file. After making some researches I came to this solution:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (path)
{
   using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path2))
   {    
      LineIndex=0;
      while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
         LineIndex++;                                
         if (LineIndex > 6)
            break;
      }

      while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
         writer.WriteLine(line);
      }
      reader.Close();
      writer.Close();

      if (File.Exists(path2))
      {
         File.Delete(path);
         File.Move(path2, path);
      }
   }
}
```

This code is supposed to read the path file, write all the lines except the first 6 in path2 file and then move the content of path2 file to path file, by overriding its previous content. But what I get is that path file get erased from all its previous data, so it becomes empty. Any solution please?

Comment: Try to delete and move after the using statements.

Comment: what is strange is that the delete/move do anything at all and don't throw an exception (as both files are opened because of the writers oO).  but else as yacoub mentioned move the file.exists block outside the using blocks and it should work as intended

Comment: I've removed the  "C#" tag from the title. See ["*Should questions include “tags” in their titles?*"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/284827), where the general consensus is "no".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take it much, much simpler:

```
File.WriteAllLines(path2, File.ReadAllLines(path).Skip(6).ToArray())
```

This works using Linq's `Skip`, which returns an array of all lines except the first 6 ones. Also note that this is working well with smaller files, because you load the entire file into memory.

Comment: This is great... until the file is huge and reading all the lines at once becomes a bad idea.

Comment: Yes, like I said. But for some reading this question it might be very useful.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked perfectly. And what if I want, for example, to skip the second 6 lines? So the path2 reads the first 6 lines, skips the second 6 lines and continues to read the other lines? P.S. the file is not huge, so this solution fits perfectly! ;)

Comment: Take a look at `.Skip` and `.Take`.